# Update запрос не срабатывает

Tags: php, firebase

При выполнении `insert` или `select` запросы выполняются отлично с помощью `ibase_query`. Но если в него попадает `update`, то я вижу ошибку 405 `Not alowed`. Какова может быть причина данной ошибки, и как можно ее исправить? С помощью IBExpert тот же самый запрос (от того же пользователя) работает нормально.